# RecyclerView with Cursor

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have been trying to understand the process and implementation of RecyclerView. I have data in cursor so i changed code as far as i could so bear it because am new to programming and development. So i tried and here is the code.But nothing is happens.

```
    public class MyContactsRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyContactsRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Cursor cursor;
private View view;
public MyContactsRecyclerViewAdapter(Cursor cur){
       cur = cursor;
}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
while(cursor.movetoNext()){
        String nam = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mDatabase.Tableinfo.Contacts_name));
        String phon = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mDatabase.Tableinfo.Contacts_phone));
        byte[] b = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(mDatabase.Tableinfo.Contact_pic));
        holder.name.setText(nam);
        holder.phone.setText(phon);
    if (b==null) {
        Profile bla = new Profile();
     holder.pic.setImageBitmap(bla.getRoundedShape(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources.getSystem(), R.drawable.samplepro),60,60));
    }   else   {
     holder.pic.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b,0,b.length));
    }
  }
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(cursor != null){
    return cursor.getCount();}
    return 0 ;
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final View mView;
    public TextView name;
    public TextView phone;
    public ImageView pic;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mView = view;
        pic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phone);
        name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    }
}}
```

and in the Main activity.....

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts_list, container, false);
    DataBaseOperations hell = new DataBaseOperations(getActivity());
    SQLiteDatabase db = hell.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {mDatabase.Tableinfo.ID,mDatabase.Tableinfo.Contacts_phone,mDatabase.Tableinfo.Contacts_name,mDatabase.Tableinfo.Contact_pic};
    Cursor Contacts = db.query(mDatabase.Tableinfo.contacts, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
      LinearLayoutManager llv = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        llv.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        contacts.setLayoutManager(llv);
        MyContactsRecyclerViewAdapter lv = new     MyContactsRecyclerViewAdapter(Contacts);
        contacts.setAdapter(lv);

            return view;
}
```

Comment: nothing happens?what it means?

Comment: it is supposed to show a vertical list i think. @FireSun

Comment: try to log the result of `getCount()`,maybe it returns 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Cursor cursor;
private View view;
public MyContactsRecyclerViewAdapter(Cursor cur){
   cur = cursor;
}
```

**cur = cursor;** is not correct. Is a copy paste error or your code not work because you are not updating properly the variable cursor?

This line should be `cursor=cur;`

Comment: Another big problem that I see is that you are trying to use a cursor inside the adapter. You should try to use a List<T>
onBindViewHolder give you a single view for a single item of your list (cursor in this case) you have a while trying to update all the items, that is wrong. You should use cursor.getItemByIndex(position) (if this method exists) and update the view with this data.